# Unable to add responsive flexboxes in a row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I'm trying to place 4 equal sized `flex`-boxes in a single row in large and medium screen
and in 2 rows (2 in each) for `sm`all screen and in a 4 rows(1 in each row) for `xs`mall screens.
Two of the flex boxes are embedded codepens and the other two image thumbnails.
As of now,all 4 `flex` boxes are not of equal sizes and appear in a column.

here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rashidnaushad/onz3ptq0/2/).

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box div.A {
  order: 1;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  min-height: auto;
}

.box div.B {
  order: 2;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  min-height: auto;
}

.box div.C {
  order: 3;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  min-height: auto;
}

.box div.D {
  order: 4;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  min-height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="box">

  <div class="A">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <p data-height="268" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="VaKMBJ" data-default-tab="result" data-user="rashidnaushad" data-preview="true" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="http://codepen.io/rashidnaushad/pen/VaKMBJ/">Simple Javascript App</a> by Rashid Naushad (<a href="http://codepen.io/rashidnaushad">@rashidnaushad</a>) on <a href="http://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="B">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <p data-height="268" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="pyPjae" data-default-tab="result" data-user="rashidnaushad" data-preview="true" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="http://codepen.io/rashidnaushad/pen/pyPjae/">Tribute to Raghuram Rajan</a> by Rashid Naushad (<a href="http://codepen.io/rashidnaushad">@rashidnaushad</a>) on <a href="http://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="C">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="img img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://cleantallahassee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/coming-soon.jpg" alt="Coming Soon!" />
      <div class="caption">
        <h5 class="text-center">Coming Soon!</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="D">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="img img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://cleantallahassee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/coming-soon.jpg" alt="Coming Soon!" />
      <div class="caption">
        <h5 class="text-center">Coming Soon!</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a very simple responsive column layout with media queries.  No change to your HTML.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/onz3ptq0/4/)

**CSS:**

```
.box {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.thumbnail {  
  height: 278px;
}
.box div.A, .box div.B, .box div.C, .box div.D  {
  float: left;
}

@media (max-width: 519px) {

.box div.A, .box div.B, .box div.C, .box div.D  {
  width: 100%;
}
}
@media (min-width: 520px) {

.box div.A, .box div.B, .box div.C, .box div.D  {
  width: 50%;
}
}
@media (min-width: 820px) {

.box div.A, .box div.B, .box div.C, .box div.D  {
  width: 25%;
}
}
```